# Create ArrayList<String> from resource string-array

Tags: android, kotlin

I have declared ArrayList like,

```
var otherSeriesList = ArrayList<String>()
```

And trying to get data from resource by following,

```
otherSeriesList = ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(resources.getStringArray(R.array.get_other_series)))
```

But I am getting error. Please see the image-
[image]

How should I create ArrayList from resource string-array?

Comment: If you have an array `foo` you can do `otherSeriesList = arrayListOf(*foo)` (note the spread operator `*` which takes care of passing the array as a vararg).

Comment: I have done like this. Please put it as answer.

Comment: One of the people that posted an answer has added this method to their answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simple do like this-

```
otherSeriesList = ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(*resources.getStringArray(R.array.get_other_series)))
```

* will pass the Array as vararg

Comment: This solution is not only look massive, but it also makes redundant `Arrays.asList` call

Answer (score 5):

Just use `ArrayList(resources.getStringArray( ... ).toMutableList())` instead.

If you don't need to use `ArrayList` exactly in your code, then you can change type of property to `MutableList<String>` and call `resources.getStringArray( ... ).toMutableList()`

Or you can use **spread operator** on your array and create `ArrayList` via call `arrayListOf(*context.resources.getStringArray())`

Comment: using `mutableListOf` is also an option

Comment: @Zoe yep, but only in case when type of property is `MutableList`. And even in such case better and easier to call `toMutableList()` instead of combining `mutableListOf` with spread operator

Answer (score 1):

You can to declare it as MutableList(). Also cast that `StringArray` to `String` before that.

```
var otherSeriesList: MutableList<String> = Arrays.asList(resources.getStringArray(R.array.get_other_series).toString())
```

Or you can do it like,

```
var otherSeriesList: MutableList<String> = resources.getStringArray(R.array.get_other_series).toMutableList()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array, simply call [`toList()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-list.html) on it.

```
val arr = arrayOf(1, 2)
val list = arr.toList()
```

Alternatively, there’s also a `toMutableList()` extension available.

**Note** that you can declare lists in Kotlin like this:

```
val list = listOf<String>(1, 2)
```

To be sure to get an `ArrayList`, use `arrayListOf()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an **[extension](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html)** function

```
 private fun Array<String>.getAsArrayList(): ArrayList<String> {
    val list = ArrayList<String>()
    this.forEach { it->list.add(it) }
    return list
}
```

and call it like this

```
val  list = resources.getStringArray(R.array.array).getAsArrayList()
```